# What is the technical term for online shopping without logging in to a particular site?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I was implementing an ecommerce gateway sometime back and I came across two terms to define online shopping where the customer logs in to the buyer's site and where online shopping is possible without logging in. I can't remember the terms now and I don't seem to find it by searching on Google.

Comment: Do you mean "user account" vs. "guest account"?

Comment: Microsoft Windows shopping? :P (Pun based on [window shopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopping#.22Window_shopping.22))

Answer (score 2):

The term I was looking for was 'Guest Checkout'